# How can i catch multiple exceptions and loop until i get valid input?

Tags: java

I have to catch 3 exceptions and loop until valid input is entered.

Right now my program ends when valid input is entered but just continuously loops with invalid input. it never catches the exceptions. If I take out the loop and enter say an 'm' it catches arithmeticException but prints the error message for inputMismatch "only numbers"

```
// Get input from user and perform integer divsion.
do{
    try{
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the numerator: ");
        numerator = keyboard.nextInt();        
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the denominator: ");
        denominator = keyboard.nextInt();
    } 
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
          System.out.println("Enter only numbers.");
    }
    catch(NegativeValueException e){
          System.out.println("no negative values.");
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e){
          System.out.println("Division by zero.");
    }

    if (numerator >=0 && denominator >= 0){
        quotient = numerator / denominator;
    }else if(numerator<0 && denominator <0){
        throw new NegativeValueException();
    }else
        invalidInput = true;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("The result of integer division is: ");
    System.out.println(quotient);
    System.out.println();
}while (invalidInput);
```

I just need to catch the exceptions and have it print out the appropriate error message for the exception and loop until valid input is entered. without the loop in there now it will catch a negative value but not print the error and ends with build failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the `break` keyword to exit the loop.

Comment: How are the exceptions expected to be caught if you only put four lines into the try block? The only exception catchable by your code is the InputMismatchException of the Scanner.

Comment: What is `NegativeValueException` ? You are catching that exception early in method but throwing it again in same method at later stage.

Comment: I think you want to use `continue` in the `catch` blocks. Or you could just move all calculation logic into the `try` block, so that it only gets executed if no exception was thrown. That way you could also catch the `NegtiveValueException` you throw. A bit ugly to use exceptions for control flow like that, but it would probably work.

Comment: Your understanding for the exceptions are incorrect. How do you expect arithmetic exception when you only receive the input without calculations? exceptions should not be use as validations or as part of the logical condition in the flow of your program. They are meant to handle cases out of your expactations.

Comment: You probably want to use `System.err` not `System.out` for messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have shown effort but you also seem new to Java , I am trying to correct your code. Usually , its not recommended for this low level of correction.

We need to throw an exception before catching it - that was the case for you around - `NegativeValueException`.

I am assuming that variables & types - `NegativeValueException` , `invalidInput` & `keyboard` are declared & defined.

I have provided sample code doing minimal changes to code put forward by you , though problem put forward by you can be solved by better code.

```
do{
        invalidInput=false;
        try{

        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the numerator: ");
        int numerator = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the denominator: ");
        int denominator = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(numerator<0 && denominator <0){
           throw new NegativeValueException();
         }else if (numerator >=0 && denominator >= 0){
        int quotient = numerator / denominator;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("The result of integer division is: ");
        System.out.println(quotient);
        System.out.println();
        }
        } catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Enter only numbers.");
            invalidInput = true;
        }catch(NegativeValueException e){
            System.out.println("no negative values.");
            invalidInput = true;
        }catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("Division by zero.");
            invalidInput = true;
        }
        }while (invalidInput);
```

Comment: That fixed my problem. I did end up in an infinite loop when entering non-numeric values but realized I had to flush the buffer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is you are doing the math outside `try-block`, say if it throws an `exception` after that the program goes through these checks:

```
if (numerator >=0 && denominator >= 0) //  false as there was exception
else if(numerator<0 && denominator <0)  // false as there was exception
else
    invalidInput = true; //gets executed
```

After each exception `invalidInput = true` gets executed and thus breaks the `do-while loop`. Move the math inside `try-block`

Try this code:

```
do
{
    try
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the numerator: ");
        numerator = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the denominator: ");
        denominator = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (numerator >=0 && denominator >= 0)
        {
            quotient = numerator / denominator;
        }
        else if(numerator<0 && denominator <0)
        {
            throw new NegativeValueException();
        }
        else
            invalidInput = true;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("The result of integer division is: ");
        System.out.println(quotient);
        System.out.println();
    } 
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter only numbers.");
    }
    catch(NegativeValueException e)
    {
        System.out.println("no negative values.");
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Division by zero.");
    }

}while (invalidInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the numerator: ");
        int numerator = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive value for the denominator: ");
        int denominator = s.nextInt();
        int quotient = numerator / denominator;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("InputMismatchException " + e);
        System.exit(0);


    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("ArithmeticException " + e);
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("NegativeValueException " + e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
} while (true);
```